# Creating a transparent video out of an input video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a video with a transparent background out of an input video (with the same dimensions, etc.). I tried several strategies (using the `chromakey` filter and others) and none worked... I got this far:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "color=color=black@0.0,format=yuva420p[bg],[bg][0:v]scale2ref[bg][0v],[bg]drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5;[0v]nullsink" -c:v qtrle -an "alpha.mov"
```

- creating a video stream with transparency, and setting a transparent background (black@0.0)
- scaling the transparent video according to the input video
- [for testing purposes: drawing a box over the transparent video. I omitted the part in which I embed subtitles onto the video, for simplicity's sake]
- discarding the input video stream
- removing the audio stream

It basically works, but **the processing never ends** - I can't manage to limit the output video length so it'll match the input video's length...
I've tried using the `-shortest` option anywhere in the command - with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to solve it with a small trick using `overlay` filter (specifically - its `shortest` parameter), with its `x` and `y` set to some coordinates outside the relevant bounds, so we're left with the effect of limiting the video's length appropriately:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "color=color=black@0.0,format=yuva420p[bg],[bg][0:v]scale2ref[bg][0v],[bg]drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5[out];[out][0v]overlay=x=100000:y=100000:shortest=1" -c:v qtrle -an "alpha.mov"
```